# How to implement a Laravel model that loads a resource

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel model that loads a resource from a remote SSH server, then stores the returned data in properties within the model.  Here is a simplified version of my code:

**SomeController.php (Controller)**

```
  $foo = new Foo();
  $foo->load(52); // Load resource #52
  echo 'The title of resource #52 is ' . $foo->getTitle();
```

**Foo.php (Model)**

```
  class Foo extends Model
  {
    private $_id;
    private $_title;
    private $_body;

    public function loadResource($id)
    {
      // ...connect to external SSH server and retrieve resource 
      $this->_id = $resource->id;
      $this->_title = $resource->title;
      $this->_body = $resource->body;
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
      return $this->_title;
    }

    public function getBody()
    {
      return $this->_body;
    }

  }
```

- Is there a better or more idiomatic way of structuring this, or some sort of pattern I should be following?
- Is there a name for this type of class?
- Is it an appropriate thing to place in a model?

Comment: Any particular reason you want all the load logic in the model instead of something like an `SSHManager` or an `SSHConnection`?

Comment: This is the only thing in my app that uses an SSH connection.  The code that opens the connection and parses the output is pretty simple.  Given that, would there be an advantage to using one of those?  I am not familiar with what they are.

Comment: The classes I suggested don't exist, it were just some examples how you could name a service responsible for retrieving the data. Because that's the point: you should, if possible, separate concerns. A database model should have nothing to do with a remote connection. But that just as an aside regarding the architecture.

Answer (score 1):

You might use the "retrieved" model event to achieve that:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events

```
class Foo extends Model
  {

    public static function boot()
    {
        static::retrieved(function (Foo $foo) {
            $foo->resource = getResource();
        )
    }
  }
```

That's gonna bind the external resource to the resource property when the model is retrieved from the database:

```
$foo = Foo::find(100);
```

Then you are able to get resource attributes via the resource property from the model.

```
$foo->resource->id;
$foo->resource->title;
$foo->resource->body;
```